# Allow users to edit ranges dynamic Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am new to VBA.

I want to add dynamic range to allow users to edit.

for example i want "column A" all the cells with no value to be allowed as range and the cells with value not allowed to edit.
by this i will allow user to add data in empty cell only with password.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SU. We are not a script writing service. Please do some research and try some things and present what you have.

Answer (score 0):

*You can try this VBA code will help to enter data in empty cells only.*

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Dim Lockable As Range
Dim Nlock As Range

Set Lockable = Range("A1:A5000")

If Intersect(Lockable, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Sheets("Your Worksheet Name").Range("E1").Value

For Each Nlock In Target
    If Nlock.Value <> "" Then
        check = MsgBox("If this entry correct,, cannot be changed.", vbYesNo, "Cell Locked")
        If check = vbYes Then
            Nlock.Locked = True
        Else
            ActiveCell.Select
        End If
    End If
Next Nlock
 ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Sheets("Your 
 Worksheet Name").Range("E1").Value

 End Sub
```

---

**N.B.**

- Range `A1:A5000` is editable.
- Enter Password in cell `E1` (is ediatble also).
- Save the Workbook as *Macro Enabled (.xlsm )*

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Currently i am using this code and it is working fine.
But i want to allow data entry with password only.
Because this sheet is shared between multiple users.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Intersect(Range("C1:D10000"), Target)
    If Not MyRange Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Chef+F&B REQUEST").Unprotect Password:="SKG"
        MyRange.Locked = True
        Sheets("Chef+F&B REQUEST").Protect Password:="SKG"
    End If
End Sub

Comment: @JunaidTahir,, glad to help you,, yes you can apply modification also,, my code has Password in cell E1,, now if U feel you can [Accept my post as answer](https://superuser.com/tour) as well Up vote too,, keep asking ☺